# What is Google's business model for Tensorflow? also why did Baidu develop PaddlePaddle

Tags: tensorflow

I heard Google has over 100 engineers working on Tensorflow. So, what does Google gain from distributing this expensive engine for free? Will Google later charge corporate Tensorflow users? ?

What is google’s plan for Tensorflow? will it be free forever? like a deep learning version of python?

Some people tell me it's to reduce new employee training time. If so, why did Baidu develop it's own deep learning library when that means they should spend extra time training it's employees who are used to using Tensorflow, how to use Baidu's deep learning library

Comment: It helps with Google Cloud strategy, like CloudML. People are afraid of lock-in, so using open stack attracts more customers.

Answer (score 2):

Well if everyone is using tensorflow there are more contributions made to it by the public. That helps google for free.

Even if it doesn't become a product that they sell they can still make money from it.

The thing is they might be able to sell services around it like lessons.  They can also sell hardware specifically optimized for tensorflow etc.

Almost every company had its own machine learning framework.  The reason they open sourced them was because each of theirs were going to fall much behind if it wasn't open source. A prime example is how Torch was doing so great up until tensorflow became open source as well.  (With google's backing and because it's in python instead of lua are a few reasons tf became more popular).